# Can I use an IN clause in this situation?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am to make a website where I would like to create all the DVD's, I am in possession of. Furthermore, I would like to place the movies into categories. I got these tables.

**categories:**
id - title

**movies:**
id - category_ref - etc......

Imagine that I have created several categories: (Action - ID: 1, Comedy - ID: 2)

When I create a movie in my adminpanel, I'll have the opportunity of choosing more categories through checkboxes. For instance, I could choose Action and Comedy for Spiderman.

The row for the move will be like this:

ID: 1   -   category_ref: 1/2 (<- that meaning Action/Comedy)

So, on the frontpage - I would like Spiderman to be shown both under Action and Comedy.

I thought, I could use IN to get the movies under the right categories, but it doesn't work as desired:

```
"SELECT id, movie_title FROM film WHERE $catID IN((REPLACE(category_ref, '/', ','))"
```

The question might appear complicated, but it's not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this situation you should use [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function:

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET($catID,(REPLACE(category_ref, '/', ','))>0
```

**BUT if you haven't design your table in this way yet USE the second table to store `movie-category` relations (See @Hugo_Delsing answer).**

Comment: Eventhough it is more advantageous to use another table structure, I will maintain the previous structure and use FIND_IN_SET - that solves my problem. So you deserve the accepted answer - thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to add more then one category to a movie, you need a third table to store it in.

```
Categories: id, title
movies: id, title
movie_categories: movieID, categoryID
```

then you could have

```
//categories
1 Action
2 Comedy

//Movies
1 Spiderman

//movie_categories
1 1   //connection between movieID 1 and categoryID 1 (spiderman & action)
1 2   //connection between movieID 1 and categoryID 2 (spiderman & comedy)
```

and then you can search

```
SELECT id, title FROM movies WHERE ID IN(SELECT movieID FROM movie_categories WHERE categoryID=$catID)
```

Comment: I can now see that I made a mistake not creating a third table that took care of combining the movies to the categories. That is the obvious way of making it. However, I will keep my construction and use FIND_IN_SET. I will never forget this way of designing the table structure. Thanks, +1 to you!